# How to count the number of times a continuous condition is true?

Tags: python, dataframe

Each row of the `A` column is compared with the A value when the `COND` column was True last time, if it is less than it, the condition is satisfied, and the count is accumulated. Stop counting until greater than or equal to.

Input:

```
import pandas as pd
A=[28,30,15,25,24,13,31,19,20,11,19,21]
COND=[False,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,True,False,False,False]
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':A,'COND':COND})
```

Expected Output

```
    A   COND    expected
0   28  FALSE   0
1   30  TRUE    0
2   15  FALSE   1
3   25  FALSE   2
4   24  FALSE   3
5   13  FALSE   4
6   31  FALSE   0
7   19  FALSE   0
8   20  TRUE    0
9   11  FALSE   1
10  19  FALSE   2
11  21  FALSE   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve this result, you need to iterate over the lists to determine the outputted values.

Start by assigning some base variables:

```
expected = []
lastTrue = None
count = 0
```

These will be modified throughout the loop.  Next, loop through and test for each condition.

Loop through the numbers:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    num = A[i]
```

Test for if the condition is True; if it is, save the number and reset the count:

```
if COND[i]:  # If True, save the number and reset count
    lastTrue = num
    count = 0
```

Check for if a True value has been found yet:

```
elif lastTrue is None:  # If haven't found a True value yet, pass
    pass
```

Test the number against the last true number to determine the output:

```
elif num < lastTrue:  # If less than the last True value, increment count
    count += 1
else:  # If larger than or equal to, reset count
    count = 0
    lastTrue = None
```

Add the current count to the list:

```
expected.append(count)
```

Now all you need to do is add the column and print the output.

**Final code:**

```
import pandas as pd
A=[28,30,15,25,24,13,31,19,20,11,19,21]
COND=[False,True,False,False,False,False,False,False,True,False,False,False]

expected = []
lastTrue = None
count = 0
for i in range(len(A)):
    num = A[i]
    if COND[i]:  # If True, save the number and reset count
        lastTrue = num
        count = 0
    elif lastTrue is None:  # If haven't found a True value yet, pass
        pass
    elif num < lastTrue:  # If less than the last True value, increment count
        count += 1
    else:  # If larger than or equal to, reset count
        count = 0
        lastTrue = None
    expected.append(count)

df=pd.DataFrame({'A':A,'COND':COND,'EXPECTED':expected})
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
      A   COND  EXPECTED
 0   28  False         0
 1   30   True         0
 2   15  False         1
 3   25  False         2
 4   24  False         3
 5   13  False         4
 6   31  False         0
 7   19  False         0
 8   20   True         0
 9   11  False         1
 10  19  False         2
 11  21  False         0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and you already have an answer. But I thought I add an answer from "within the Pandas framework" (i.e. avoiding explicit iteration over dataframe rows).

You could try:

```py
df["Res"] = df.groupby(df["COND"].cumsum()).agg(
    Res=("COND", "cumcount"), A_cummax=("A", "cummax")
).assign(
    A_first=df["A"].where(df["COND"]).ffill().fillna(df["A"]),
    Res=lambda df: df["Res"].where(df["A_cummax"] <= df["A_first"], 0)
)["Res"]
```

- `df["COND"].cumsum()` identifies the groups you want to address, so grouping over it is the first step.
- Then add two columns via `.agg()`: (1) `Res` build by `.cumcount()` is almost the result you're looking for, but has to be adjusted a bit. (2) An auxiliary column `A_cummax`.
- Afterwards add a second auxiliary column `A_first` that identifies the resp. first `A`-values. The dataframe now looks like:

  ```
      Res  A_cummax  A_first
  0     0        28     28.0
  1     0        30     30.0
  2     1        30     30.0
  3     2        30     30.0
  4     3        30     30.0
  5     4        30     30.0
  6     5        31     30.0
  7     6        31     30.0
  8     0        20     20.0
  9     1        20     20.0
  10    2        20     20.0
  11    3        21     20.0
  ```
- Finally the adjustment of `Res` based on the 2 auxiliary columns: The zeros after the first `A`-value is exceeded.

Result for your example is as expected:

```
     A   COND  Res
0   28  False    0
1   30   True    0
2   15  False    1
3   25  False    2
4   24  False    3
5   13  False    4
6   31  False    0
7   19  False    0
8   20   True    0
9   11  False    1
10  19  False    2
11  21  False    0
```